# How to set class path for javaBean class?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm creating a jasper report. I need to use java-Bean class. Its return collection.
this is my code.

```
public class fbsBean {

    private String p_name;
    private String p_age;
    private String date;
    private String value;

    public fbsBean(){}
    public String getname(){
        return p_name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.p_name=name;
    }
    public String getAge(){
        return p_age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age){
        this.p_age=age;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String Date){
        this.date=Date;
    }
    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String Value){
        this.value=Value;
    }
    public static Collection getFbs(){
        Vector fbs= new Vector();
        fbsBean fb= new fbsBean();
        fb.setName("Harshana");
        fb.setAge("22");
        fb.setDate("12/12/12");
        fb.setValue("96");
        return fbs;
    }
}
```

when i use this class to my report it show this. please help me.

[image]

Comment: too small font.. can you specify which class not found

Comment: please check if both classes are in BeanClass package

Comment: @GV fbsBean class. I used class path as BeanClass.fbsBean. BeanClass is the Package name .

Comment: only one in here. BeanClass is the package name class name is fbsBean @Satya

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the bean properties in your file.

Add the following line after your useBean statement like this.

Problem solved. I think you are building Java file against 1.7, which iReports can't seem to read it seems. Building for 1.6 solves the problem and the above code works fine.